# Why do the allKeys and allValues methods of NSDictionary return NSArray and not NSSet?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsset

Naturally, the keys of a `NSDictionary` are not ordered, and so are its values.

So, why do the `allKeys` and `allValues` methods of `NSDictionary` return `NSArray` and not `NSSet`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A value can occur more than once in a dictionary but not in a set. So returning an array returns all the values, while returning a set would return only the unique values.

Keys of course must be unique, so I'd suggest the choice of array rather than set is simple consistency.